# Gap infront of horizontal unordered list

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I want to create a website for my self with fullpage.js and I am running into some trouble with some elements. I have this unordered list and I want to center the list so that the items are centered. I have tried everything but nothing works. I have this floating div that is centered and the list is slightly pushed to the right. Here is the code:

```css
.homepage-block{
    display: table;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#icons{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: center;
}

li{
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.fab{
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Danijel Tomić - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha256-+dIh4jG2jQTHZwW81yUo8h6tzXWcNumyNL5XPZbwp1E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8d59324b96.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullPage">
        <div class="section s1 bg-primary">
            <div class="homepage-block">
                <h1>Danijel</h1>
                <hr>
                <ul id="icons">
                    <li><i class="fab fa-github"></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section s2">
            <h1>hello</h1>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="section s3">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        new fullpage('#fullPage', {
            autoScrolling: true,
            navigation: true,
            navigationTooltips: ['Home', 'Projects', 'Contact'],
            anchors: ['section1', 'section2', 'seciton3'],
            showActiveTooltip: true,
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By default `<ul>` element have padding left `40px`, reset it with `ul { padding:0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Zohir said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938938/gap-infront-of-horizontal-unordered-list#comment107813316_60938938), by default UL elements have a `padding-left: 40px`, however in chrome they also have `padding-inline-start: 40px;` in their default stylesheet.

This should work for both:

```
ul, ol {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```